# Creating a Column Based on Column Text in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe (series) `'df'` that looks like the following:

```
Name
A1001
A1002
B1001
C1001
A1003
B1002
B1003
C1002
D1001
D1002
```

I want to create a new column called Company which should read `'Alpha'` if text starts with `'A'`, `'Bravo'` if text starts with `'B'` and `'Others'` if text starts with anything else.

I tried:

```
df['Company'] = 'Alpha' if df.Name.str.startswith('A') else 'Other'
```

But it gave me an error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Expected Output:

```
Name     Company
A1001    Alpha
A1002    Alpha
B1001    Bravo
C1001    Other
A1003    Alpha
B1002    Bravo
B1003    Bravo
C1002    Other
D1001    Other
D1002    Other
```

How can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) to create multi-conditional column:

```
letter = df['Name'].str[0]
df['Company'] = np.select([letter.eq('A'), letter.eq('B')], ['Alpha', 'Bravo'], default='Other')

    Name Company
0  A1001   Alpha
1  A1002   Alpha
2  B1001   Bravo
3  C1001   Other
4  A1003   Alpha
5  B1002   Bravo
6  B1003   Bravo
7  C1002   Other
8  D1001   Other
9  D1002   Other
```

---

Same approach, but now we use a more "self explaining" code:

```
letter = df['Name'].str[0]
conditions = [letter.eq('A'), letter.eq('B')]
choices = ['Alpha', 'Bravo']

df['Company'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default='Other')
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with [`Series.str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html):

```
df['Company'] = np.select([df.Name.str.startswith('A'), 
                           df.Name.str.startswith('B')], 
                           ['Alpha', 'Bravo'], 
                           default='Other')
print (df)
    Name Company
0  A1001   Alpha
1  A1002   Alpha
2  B1001   Bravo
3  C1001   Other
4  A1003   Alpha
5  B1002   Bravo
6  B1003   Bravo
7  C1002   Other
8  D1001   Other
9  D1002   Other
```

Comment: It' working, but the values are not matching.  Some of the As are assigned 'Other'.